# React: useRef for multiple components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

I have a custom component with multiple sub components like this:

```
interface MyComponentProps {
  ref: any; 
}; 

function MyComponent(props: MyComponentProps){
  return <>
  <input id="name" type="number" />
  <input id="age" type="text" />
  </>
}
```

I'd like `props.ref` to contain values of **all** subcomponents, when accessed from the outside.
Example: `myref.current?.value.name` and `myref.current?.value.age` should be possible. How do I do that?

Constraints:

- Why am I searching for a ref-solution?

  - I'd like to keep the interface of the component as *native-felt* as possible.

Comment: Does this help

https://eliaslog.pw/how-to-add-multiple-refs-to-one-useref-hook/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a ref for each *other* component, then combine those into a single ref.

```js
const App = () => {
    const ref = React.useRef();
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log(ref.current.nameRef.current.value);
      console.log(ref.current.ageRef.current.value);
    }, 1000);
    return <MyComponent combinedRef={ref} />;
};
function MyComponent(props){
  const nameRef = React.useRef();
  const ageRef = React.useRef();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    props.combinedRef.current = { nameRef, ageRef };
  }, []);
  return <div>
    <input id="name" type="number" ref={nameRef} />
    <input id="age" type="text" ref={ageRef} />
  </div>;
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

That said, this is a very odd pattern to want to have in React - it doesn't go well at all with how React control flow should usually be, I wouldn't recommend it.

If you must use the exact path `myref.current?.value.name`, you'll need to make both inputs controlled components, and then inside MyComponent, do:

```
props.combinedRef.current = {
  value: { // should there really be an extra level of nesting here?
    name,
    age
  }
}
```

Comment: very helpful. I tweaked it to `props.combinedRef.current = { name: nameRef.current?.value, age: ageRef.current?.value, };`